# Image name appears after every image i echo on my php table. How do i hide this text? (mysql and php)

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

As you can see in the picture below, the name of the picture file appears after every image. I dont want the image name to be displayed. Is there any way of hiding the name so per.jfif, ola.jfif and arne.jfif doesnt appear?

I have been searching on here for an answer, but it doesnt seem to have been asked on here before. Thanks for the help in advance,

[image: Table view]

Below this text you can see my messy code.

```
    <?php
    $tilkobling = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","oppgave_normalisering");
    $sql = "SELECT person_table.personr, person_table.navn, person_table.adresse, person_table.mobilnr, person_table.postnr, person_table.bilde, mobil_table.model, sted_table.sted FROM mobil_table, person_table, sted_table WHERE person_table.personr = sted_table.stednr AND person_table.personr = mobil_table.modelnr";
    $datasett = $tilkobling->query($sql)
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Startside</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="startside.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/normalisering_oppgave/per.php">Per</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/normalisering_oppgave/ola.php">Ola</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/normalisering_oppgave/arne.php">Arne</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<table >
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Nr<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Navn<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Adresse<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Postnr</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Sted</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Mobilnr</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Modell</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Bilde</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while ($rad = mysqli_fetch_array($datasett)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["personr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["navn"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["adresse"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["postnr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["sted"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["mobilnr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["model"]; ?></td>
                        <td><img src="<?= $rad['bilde'] ?>" alt="" style="height:100px; width:140px;" id="bilde"> <?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You print image name in your last `td`. Just remove `<?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?>`.

```php
<td>
   <!-- ↓↓ this is image element -->
   <img src="<?= $rad['bilde'] ?>" alt="" style="height:100px; width:140px;" id="bilde"> 
   <!-- ↓↓ delete this ↓↓ -->
   <?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont Need This part

```
<?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?>
```